# How can i return true if 1 parameter is true and return false if the 2 parameters are true without using If-else statements

Tags: java, conditional-statements

so , as the title says 
i have 2 ints where if (only) one of them is between (13 , 19) , return true 
but if both ints are between (13 , 19) return false
without using if-else Statements
sry if its a lame question , still learning the ropes here

```
public boolean hasOnly1Teen(int age1 , int age2)
{
    boolean is1Teen = (age1 >= 13 && age1 <= 19 ) , is2Teen = (age2 >= 13 && age2 <=19);
    return (!( is1Teen == true && is2Teen == true ));
```

Comment: `return (is1Teen && !is2Teen) || (!is1Teen && is2Teen);`

Comment: What is your aversion to using "if" statements?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS that worked ! 
thanks

Comment: This sounds like a logic homework question you didn't want to do ...

Comment: Should try the ^ (XOR) operator as well.

Comment: @JSextonn can u give an example ?

Comment: @AntonH its a homework but i am really determined to solve it not the other way around :D

Comment: @ShaDiliX `return is1Teen ^ is2Teen;`

Comment: Thanks @JSextonn !

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`return ((is1Teen == true || is2Teen == true ) && !(is1Teen == true && is2Teen == true );`

or simply use the logical xor operator.

`return (is1Teen ^ is2Teen);`

Comment: thanks , the instructor is so strict about not using something we have not taken during the course but its good to know that xor operator

Comment: I have given two choices. Use the one you prefer. But most importantly, try to learn how each works.